# How to Capture Phone Call State in Window Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to Capture Phone Call Status in Windows 7 Mobile Phone Please Help me. and then want to Make a Event CallStateChanged Passing Event Argument State Name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with the current SDK.

Comment: I want to run a Application after call disconnection , Please suggest any alternate for windows 7 and windows 8 phones

Comment: There's no real alternate to automatically do that. The user would have to launch the app manually after they've disconnected.